# How can i set animation command only once in the Update function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Animations : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum AnimatorStates
    {
        WALK, RUN, IDLE
    }

    private Animator _anim;

    void Awake()
    {
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void PlayState(AnimatorStates state)
    {
        string animName = string.Empty;
        switch (state)
        {
            case AnimatorStates.WALK:
                animName = "Walk";
                break;
            case AnimatorStates.RUN:
                animName = "Run";
                break;
        }
        if (_anim == null)
            _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

        _anim.Play(animName);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (MyCommands.walkbetweenwaypoints == true)
        {
            PlayState(AnimatorStates.RUN);
        }
        else
        {
            PlayState(AnimatorStates.IDLE);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is working fine but i don't think it's right to call the PlayState so many times in the Update. I want that if it's RUN or IDLE state to call it only once in the Update function.

Once walkbetweenwaypoints is true or false it will call the state nonstop in the Update function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the last state in Update method and only update if state has actually changed:

```
AnimatorStates lastState = AnimatorStates.IDLE;
public void PlayState(AnimatorStates state)
{
    if(state != lastState)
    {
        string animName = string.Empty;
        switch (state)
        {
            case AnimatorStates.WALK:
                animName = "Walk";
                break;
            case AnimatorStates.RUN:
                animName = "Run";
                break;
        }
        if (_anim == null)
            _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

        _anim.Play(animName);

        lastState = state;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i use it then in the Update function ? And how to include also the state WALK in case i chose the WALK state. There are 3 states.

Comment: The change I suggested to 'PlayState' method will ensure no action will be made on '_anim' unless the state given to 'PlayState' is different from the last state. This is enough as an answer to your question. 'WALK' state will work the same way other states are working inside 'PlayState' method. But you just need to use it in 'Update' method. You have just not used it in your sample code.